# Django filter "__contains" lookup throwing " is not defined"

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to get all the objects in my database that the name is  LIKE '%something%'

After reading the documentation and searching online I figured out that using django I would have to use __contains lookup.

But when I try to, the console throws me an error 500
'NameError: name 'ingredient_name__contains' is not defined'

My model is the following:

```py
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    article_number = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ingredient_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    cost_amount = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.1)])
    cost_per_unit = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
    unit = models.ForeignKey(MeasurementUnit,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ingredient_name
```

And the filtering method is:

```py
def filter(request, filter):
    filtered = Ingredient.objects.all().filter(ingredient_name__contains(filter))
```

I can't figure out what I missing in this, it's driving me mad.

If anyone could help I qould really appreciate it!

Comment: It is `ingredient_name__contains=filter`, so with `=`, not `(..)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filtering is in Django done through named parameters, so you should filter with:

```
def filter(request, filter):
    filtered = Ingredient.objects.filter(ingredient_name__contains=filter)
    # …
```

Comment: Thank you, very, very much!